# Errors appearing in code

Tags: c#

Help, I don't know what this error is

```
Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 " = " answer);
```

This returns four errors (im using monodevelop)

1. ) expected
2. ; expected
3. ; expected (yes, it appear twice)
4. Invalid expression term ')'
   And three more similar lines got the same errors

Here is the whole code

```
using System;

namespace CMD_test
{
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Start:
        double num1;
        double num2;
        double answer;

        Console.WriteLine ("What operation shall we use? Type:");
        Console.WriteLine ("A - for addition");
        Console.WriteLine ("S - for subtraction");
        Console.WriteLine ("M - for multiplication");
        Console.WriteLine ("D - for division");

        KeyPress:
        string key = Console.Read ();

        if (key == "A") {
            Console.WriteLine ("You chose addition");
            Console.Write ("What is the first number? ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("What is the second number? ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            answer = num1 + num2;
            Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 " = " answer);
        }
        if (key == "S") {
            Console.WriteLine ("You chose subtraction");
            Console.Write ("What is the first number? ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("What is the second number? ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            answer = num1 - num2;
            Console.WriteLine (num1 + " - " + num2 " = " answer);
        }
        if (key == "M") {
            Console.WriteLine ("You chose multiplication");
            Console.Write ("What is the first number? ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("What is the second number? ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            answer = num1 * num2;
            Console.WriteLine (num1 + " * " + num2 " = " answer);
        } else if (key == "D") {
            Console.WriteLine ("You chose division");
            Console.Write ("What is the first number? ");
            num1 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            Console.Write ("What is the second number? ");
            num2 = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());
            answer = num1 / num2;
            Console.WriteLine (num1 + " / " + num2 " = " answer);
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine ("You pressed a wrong button! Please retry.");
            goto KeyPress;
        }

        Console.Write ("Do you want to do another operation? Y/N: ");

        string restart = Console.ReadLine ();
        if (restart == "Y") {
            Console.Clear ();
            goto Start;
        } else if (restart == "N") {
            Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey ();
        }
    }
}
}
```

and maybe some more other errors i dont know

Comment: Just add ' + ' before ' answer ' variable in ' WriteLine ' function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expression

```
Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 " = " answer);
```

isn't valid as you have missed a couple of `+`'s off your expression. Change it to:

```
Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + answer);
```

and it'll compile correctly. Better yet, do this and you'll avoid such typos:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, answer);
```

Oh and as an aside, as and when you switch to C# 6, you'll be able to do this, which simplifies things even more:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{num1} + {num2} = {answer}");
```

Comment: Or even `Console.WriteLine ("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, num1 + num2);`

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 " = " answer);
```

should actually be

```
Console.WriteLine (num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + answer);
```

You missed two plus signs. That's why it is generating a error.
Your IDE has told you where the problem actually is.

Moreover, it is not a good practice to concatenate strings this way. `Console.WriteLine` lets you use string formatting:

```
Console.WriteLine ("{0} + {1} = {2}", num1, num2, answer);
```

Read about composite formatting here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here is an example of what you tried to do.